# customvalidation, the field i needed only more than 0 and less than 366

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub cvActivationVoidTrxnDay_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles cvActivationVoidTrxnDay.ServerValidate

    If txtActivationVoidTrxnDay.Text > "0" And txtActivationVoidTrxnDay.Text < "366" Then
        cvActivationVoidTrxnDay.ErrorMessage = "Please enter in between 0 to 366 days only."
        args.IsValid = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I need the field to be validated by only entering more than 0 or less than 366. i have tried this but i dont get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to evaluate a range on strings, than will never work. You have to cast or convert the TextBox inputs to `int`

Try:

```
If Convert.ToInt32(txtActivationVoidTrxnDay.Text) > 0 And Convert.ToInt32(txtActivationVoidTrxnDay.Text) < 366 Then
```

Or you could use a [range validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt(v=vs.71).aspx) on the client side. But it's still wise to also validate in the backend in case client side javascript is disabled.

Comment: thank bro i totaly forgot about range validator. well i got the result

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your comparing `Integers`... This will not throw an error if value can't be parsed...

```
 Dim intDays As Integer = 0
 If Integer.TryParse(txtActivationVoidTrxnDay.Text, intDays) AndAlso Not intDays > 0 AndAlso Not intDays < 366 Then
    cvActivationVoidTrxnDay.ErrorMessage = "Please enter in between 0 to 366 days only."
    args.IsValid = False
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                                                    <asp:RangeValidator id="rvActivationVoidTrxnDay" ControlToValidate="txtActivationVoidTrxnDay" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="366" Type="Integer" ErrorMessage="Please enter in between 0 to 366 days only." runat="server"> </asp:RangeValidator>
```